# How to index html, css, and javascript using solr

Tags: search, solr, lucene, indexing

Users of [CodePen](http://codepen.io) submit html/css/javascript each time they save a pen.  We're setting up Solr search and I'd like to know if any work has been done to properly tokenize html/css/js for optimal retrieval.

For example in javascript, we'd like code like

`window.location = 'http://wufoo.com'`

to produce a search hit on `window`, `location` and `window.location`.

Also, for html, we don't wish to strip out brackets on elements like `<form>` or `<field>`.

Before I go down the road of writing a custom field type, I'd like to know if anyone has already tackled this problem.  Since we index each field individually, we'll need a separate tokenizer with rules specific for css, html, and javascript.

Comment: Not stripping the brackets off html elements for test searching seems an interesting choice, when you want to remove formatting/punctuation from everything else.  What happens with attributes?

Comment: @femtoRgon exactly...  We don't specifically know what we want, but we'd like to know if others have thought through this problem.  It seems that others have indexed js/html/css and could share best practices.